# How to resize my text box?

Tags: java, swing, jtextcomponent

Main reason for exception message is display only one line but my exception message is contains more than 4 lines.
How can i resize my text box?

Comment: What the heck are you even talking about?  I realize there's a language barrier to overcome here, but nothing in this question makes sense.

Comment: How to develop web services>

Comment: Pick a language/framework/technology/etc. and start with some tutorials.  We can help you with specific questions about specific problems you encounter while programming, but a single Stack Overflow question can't provide you with complete end-to-end tutoring services.  We answer questions, we don't teach you how to program.

Comment: How to develop consumer  web services  ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not specific enough , but to answer your question I recommend you use ***[JTextArea](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)*** where you can have multiple lines for the text you are trying to display.

Also please refer [Oracle tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html) to get these basic concepts clear.

Comment: This should be a comment.